# How to connect Thorlabs KIM101 to Raspberry Pi and control with Python?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, driver, raspberry-pi3

Raspberry pi 3 running linux 10 is not interfacing correctly with USB input Thorlabs KIM101 piezoelectric motor controller

Terminal command

```
lsusb
```

detects USB input correctly but running Pylablib command in IDE

```
thorlabs.list_kinesis_devices()
```

simply returns

```
[]
```

and any commands issued return 'device not found' error.
Reading through everything, it isn't clear what drivers are needed to make this work and I think it might be a driver issue as can't think of any other reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)